# Knitr output to markdown in Rstudio

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I would like to create custom markdown output in RStudio, but Knitr parses the R code block even with the 'asis' option.  The format I'd like is 'markdown_phpextra' with the ':' character removed from table output.

My current effort so far in a .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_phpextra

---

Here's some test code:
```{r, results='asis'}
result<-knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
print(gsub(":","",result))
```
````

And the results:

```
Here's some test code:

~~~~ r
result<-knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
print(gsub(":","",result))
~~~~

|                   |   mpg|  cyl|  disp|   hp|  drat|     wt|   qsec|   vs|   am|  gear|  carb|
|-------------------|-----:|----:|-----:|----:|-----:|------:|------:|----:|----:|-----:|-----:|
| Mazda RX4         |  21.0|    6|   160|  110|  3.90|  2.620|  16.46|    0|    1|     4|     4|
| Mazda RX4 Wag     |  21.0|    6|   160|  110|  3.90|  2.875|  17.02|    0|    1|     4|     4|
| Datsun 710        |  22.8|    4|   108|   93|  3.85|  2.320|  18.61|    1|    1|     4|     1|
| Hornet 4 Drive    |  21.4|    6|   258|  110|  3.08|  3.215|  19.44|    1|    0|     3|     1|
| Hornet Sportabout |  18.7|    8|   360|  175|  3.15|  3.440|  17.02|    0|    0|     3|     2|
| Valiant           |  18.1|    6|   225|  105|  2.76|  3.460|  20.22|    1|    0|     3|     1|
```

If I simply run this code in R the output appears like this, which is what I'd like to get using Knitr:

```
|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
|-----------------|----|---|----|---|----|-----|-----|--|--|----|----|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320| 18.61|  1|  1|    4|    1|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215| 19.44|  1|  0|    3|    1|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440| 17.02|  0|  0|    3|    2|
|Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105| 2.76| 3.460| 20.22|  1|  0|    3|    1|
```

Note the extra ':' in the Knitr Markdown output.  I don't know how to remove these.

Comment: does `kable(..., format = 'markdown')` work? the colons determine the cell alignment by the way, don't you want that?

Comment: Why another markdown format? :) `pandoc` already supports 4 different table styles. Anyway, your `gsub` call should work fine by passing `"-"` as `replacement` instead of an empty string.